# is this a correct use of the word feasible

Tags: meaning

"Having all these traits is infeasible."

Is this sentence correct?
I'm not sure if this is the right use of the word 'infeasible'.

Comment: Yes. You could get the answer lickety-split in fact by merely looking it up in any good dictionary.

Comment: I did. However, in all of the dictionaries, it said hard to easily achieve; therefore, I couldn't be sure if I could use it with traits.

Comment: You need to add actual quotes, linked and attributed.

Comment: Would you expect to *achieve* a trait? An goal or accomplishment, yes, but a tree, a train, or a trait?

Comment: "feasible" is usually used to describe the process of achieving some results. It's not usually used to describe the results themselves.

Comment: The problem is maybe that traits are innate, they're not things you have and lose. "Finding all these traits (in one person/thing) is infeasible" is OK. Also "infeasible" is quite a fancy word only used in formal or literary contexts: talking to your friends you'd say "unlikely" or "not gonna happen". But you need to explain in your question precisely what you are trying to communicate and where.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too easy. Admittedly [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infeasible)] highlights the 'not easily attained/brought about', 'impracticable' sense:

> **infeasible**: not feasible [impracticable]

but it is not improper to choose [the sense of *feasible* they](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feasible#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20capable%20of%20being%20done,explanation%20that%20seemed%20feasible%20enough) also give meaning 'quite possible, likely':

> **feasible**: ...
>
> (3) reasonable, likely
>
> - *gave an explanation that seemed feasible enough*.

I'd say this licenses 'Having all these traits is infeasible'. Though I'd certainly reword this ('would be most unlikely').